# What types of conditions in an early civilization would create a religion that values joy, celebration, camaraderie and loyalty?

Tags: civilization, religion, ancient-history

I’m currently in the early stages of building cultures in a high fantasy setting, and what I initially have to work with is a couple of deities- one of which embodies joy, celebration, camaraderie and loyalty. They will not be the only deity in their own civilization’s pantheon, but presently they are the only one I have thought of. I’ve been toying with the idea of their exact domain evolving over time, likely corresponding with the development of the people that worship them.

Granted that I would like to keep the development of my pantheons consistent to how real-life religions develop, and that all that I can think of based off of this description is that, at some point, the deity’s associated civilization became prosperous enough to place more value on fun and celebration, what would be some conditions during a civilization’s development that would lead to such values being deemed important enough to assign a deity to?

Comment: For a well-known example in a well-known pantheon, see [Castor and Pollux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Castor_and_Pollux), also known as the Dioscuri, the Heavenly Boys. Currently watching over us as the constellation [Gemini](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gemini_(constellation)), the Twins.

Comment: Pretty much every living religion places some value on joy, celebration and camaraderie. They only differ in how it is regulated. Even religions stereotyped as particularly dour such as Calvinism and Wahhabism still have celebrations and strong in group loyalty

Answer (score 7):

I would say you can't have a civilization develop without valuing camrederie and loyalty.

For a group of individuals to work well together, they need to trust that each of them will pull in the same direction, and everything in all civilization shouts that basic concept: walls protect who is inside from who is outside, because who is inside is trusted to be worth protection.

All civilization put great pride in marking their own standing out from the rest of the other people: the Greek notoriously called barbarian those who could not speak Greek but only babble some other language, and other cultures call themselves "men" while outsiders are not.

If being part of a civilization is then good, as proven by its growth, it then again makes sense to celebrate it, as a mean to reinforce the identity and sense of belonging.

Answer (score 3):

The same conditions that we humans evolved under.

Relatively speaking, we are physically pathetic predators. We have no fangs, no claws, no armor, no spikes. Our senses are distinctly non-predator like, we are pretty much scent-blind compared to dogs, cats, and other predators; our hearing sucks, even our eyesight, although good compared to many predators, doesn't match an Eagle's, and our night vision is pathetic compared to a house cat.

We are not physically strong compared to most animals our size, we do not run fast compared to most animals our size, or most prey our size for that matter.

We are "pursuit" predators which is one step above scavengers like vultures eating the carcasses of animals that died by other means.

What we do have is intelligence. We can outwit our prey and all of our competition. But due to our weaknesses, that demands cooperation. Our chances of survival and reproduction are vastly improved by living together in tribes, cooperating and sharing our food, working together to make shelters and protections against those "better" physical predators made for direct combat (unlike us), and sharing the responsibilities of communities.

On the small scale of a hundred or so adults, we are natural socialists in our expectations. We hunt and gather collectively and share our kills and finds. We share in childcare, we take care of our sick, we punish our shirkers for not pulling their weight, and we punish the selfish that prove they cannot be trusted to do what is best for the tribe. We may banish them from the tribe or even kill them.

Comraderie and Loyalty are rewarded; with emotions. We love and value our brothers and sisters all pulling for the same thing, to the best of their ability.

We have trouble translating this to the large scale; once we pass the point of "everyone knows everyone" and we all grew up together, this tribal dynamic can break down.

But size has only become an issue in the last 20,000 years or so; recent in evolutionary terms, and we have not fully adapted to tribes of thousands or millions or billions. We may never.

But for your purposes, the conditions that prevail are a **need** for groups in order to survive, be successful in the world, and reproduce. We need comraderie and loyalty in order to survive a lethally dangerous world. If we cannot trust the people beside us, we are better off on our own.

The only tangible (non-emotional) benefit of social groups is synergy: What we can do together exceeds the sum of what we can all do alone. For many predators, that isn't true. But it is true for wolves, for example, they can bring down far bigger game acting as a pack than they could bring down alone. Wolf packs are a social system that includes love, friendship, play and comraderie. Wolves will risk their lives to protect those in their pack.

For example, we often see stories of family dogs that braved fire to save their [human] pack. Wolves and dogs run from fire. They understand fire. But their emotional ties to their pack will override their fear of fire, to warn others, to collect even kittens from the fire. And we don't often read of the ones that died trying to save their family. Those are emotions in the dog; not training. Love is what drives a dog into a burning house, through fire and pain, risking death to save another.

The cultural condition you need is lethal danger that demands camaraderie and loyalty to counter it. For wolves and humans and other pack animals, that lethal danger was just wild nature itself; and synergy that made us better together than we could be if we all went solo.

The opposite condition is a world in which going solo is just as effective a life strategy as being in a group. That may be the case in much of the modern world; many adults don't really require friends or family to get by and be happy. We want laws and such, but that is just paying some taxes. Technology means we don't have to hunt, or build together, or share the burdens of childcare, or protection from outsiders. We can just work our job and enjoy our entertainments without any strong ties to anybody else. We can be loners, or loner couples or families living together but maintaining primarily anonymous contact with society. The doctor, the mechanic, the grocer, even your employer, is perfectly willing to engage without knowing a thing about your personal life. You can be just another anonymous customer or employee. Because there is very little danger in that, for you or them.

Answer (score 2):

**The trickster god.**

It seems paradoxical of course, but it's long been observed that people's define their culture by adversity, suffering - the trickster embodies this.

In contrast to L.Dutch's belonging and cohesiveness within a group, there is always the force of individualism, of mischief and at the extreme, malice. These things need a name so that they can be shamed into subservience.

They will be cursed for a poor hunt, a broken tool, a bad harvest, a death or disease. Unruly children can be brought to some semblance of good behaviour with a threat that the trickster will get to them.

Strangers will be dealt with by mistrust until they prove their worth by mocking the doings of trickster gods and the suffering they cause.

As soon as the mockery of suffering is out the way, the trickster appeased, then trust is established and recognition of fellowship is to the fore. (Think Gimli and Legolas)

Answer (score 2):

**Bread and Games.**

[image]

[image]

also known as *State Sanctioned Fun.*

The state and church work together to keep society stable. In other words the peasants make food, the craftsmen make everything else, the army protects us, and the nobles do administration. Part of the administration is to organise mass festivals six times a year.

Everyone that meets their obligations to society gets to come to the festival. There is wine and music and dancing and meat and cakes.  Everyone gets fancy dress and for the rest of the night there is no difference between the poor and the rich.

This is an incentive for everyone to stay in their place the rest of the year. Otherwise they cannot attend the festival. Naturally the state and church incorporate this societal practice into their religion. The festivals are on the birthdays of the six major gods, plus an additional festival every leap year on the birthday of the god of celebration. On the other hand it is blasphemy to have a party on any other day of the year. This ensures people work hard the rest of the time.